# Querystring causes IE to show error

Tags: internet-explorer, query-string

I have a problem when I send IE to the following location: `http://fdvweb.mal/db/historikk/db_historikk_liste.asp?SQLfilter=SELECT TaKompHistorikk.*, TaKomponent.KompNummer, TaKomponent.KompNavn, TaKomponent.KompPlassering FROM TaKomponent RIGHT OUTER JOIN TaKompHistorikk ON [TaKomponent].[KompId]=[TaKompHistorikk].[KompHistorikkKompId] WHERE KompHistorikkSak = 'Servicerapport' AND (KompHistorikkStatusnummer <> '9999' OR IsNull(KompHistorikkStatusnummer) ) AND ((KompHistorikkStatusNavn <> 'OK' OR IsNull(KompHistorikkStatusNavn) ) OR ((KompHistorikkTittel <> '' OR KompHistorikkFritekst <> '') AND KompHistorikkTittel <> 'Kontrollert OK')) AND KompHistorikkDato >%3D %232/17/2010%23 ORDER BY KompNummer ASC` (localhost, I've edited the hosts file). The source-code of the file db_historikk_liste.asp is as following:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <% Response.Write Request.QueryString("SQLfilter") %>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, IE gives me the error `Internet Explorer has modified this page to help  prevent cross-site scripting.`

Anyone know how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the header `X-XSS-Protection: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the query string portion in HttpUtility.UrlEncode()

Comment: You mean like `<% Response.Write HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("SQLfilter")) %>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

fetch('//offline-news-api.herokuapp.com/stories')
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(stories) {
        console.log(stories);
    });
```